# How to identify whether a molecule is planar

Tags: organic-chemistry, symmetry

While solving for plane of symmetry of molecules I came across 1,3-dichlorocyclobutane (**1**) and I realized it does not have any plane of symmetry because we don't know whether hydrogen and chlorine are in same plane. How to judge which plane do the substituents belong to?

Similarly for compound **2**, but in compound **3** it is known that both the planes of the rings are perpendicular. Is there some kind of rule for it?

[image: 1: 1,3-dichlorocyclobutane; 2: 2‐[(2E)‐1,3‐oxathietan‐2‐ylidene]‐1,3‐oxathietane; 3: 2‐[(P)‐1,3‐oxathietan‐2‐ylidenemethylidene]‐1,3‐ oxathietane]

Comment: First you must unknow a number of things that you already know. 1,3-dichlorocyclobutane (any isomer) **does** have a plane of symmetry. This has nothing to do with being planar, though.

Comment: @IamAlita You can do it yourself using free 3D molecular editors like [MolView](https://molview.org/) or  [Jmol](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmol/) (which will also find and draw symmetry elements for you). I think there is not much to elaborate in a "show, don't tell" case like this.

Comment: There are levels upon levels of different approximations to reality, and jumping two levels up does not do the learner any good. For the purposes of this question, consider the 4-membered cycle planar.

Comment: @IvanNeretin do you mean that we dont need to know whether the molecule is planar or not in order to determine plane is symmetry?

Comment: It might be easier if instead of 'plane of symmetry' you used 'mirror plane' instead as the atoms do not need to be in the plane but appear identical when viewed in a mirror. Molecule 1 has 3 such mirror planes.

Comment: @Saniya To find out mirror plane, we need to know the geometry of molecule - **all** of it. Consequently, we'll know everything that follows. The molecule does not have to be planar, though.

Comment: @I am Alita  For simplicity  and to help the IP I assumed the molecule is as drawn with a flat ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of a plane of symmetry is easier to understand with molecules which are planar by itself.  Benzene, for example, has such a plane which may accommodate simultaneously all carbon and hydrogen atoms:

[image]

However, planarity of molecules is not a requirement to identify such planes.

Even if a construction of the cyclobutane molecule with model kit illustrates you the non-planarity of the molecule

[image]

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclobutane))

you drawing depicts it like it were planar; because you defined drawing plane where carbon atoms alternate to be either closely above, or below this level in common.  For compound **1** illustrating 1,3-dichloro cyclobutane, however, the symmetry analysis is much affected by the configuration of the two special carbon atoms.  Either you find the two chlorine atoms on the same side of this plane (*syn*)

[image]

or you find them directing to different sides (*anti*):

[image]

The interactive training set by [Symmetry@Otterbein](http://faculty.otterbein.edu/djohnston/sym/gallery/index.html) may be a helpful resource for you.  Note that the representation of compound **2** is a simplification, and the symmetry attributed strongly depends on the underlying geometry.